# Changes in constants do not take effect on JSP

Tags: java, jsp

I have a constant defined in a java interface (`Constants`) as follows:

```
public final static int DEFAULT_VAL = 2;
```

this is being used in several JSPs in my code as:

```
if (sample.hasModule(Constants.DEFAULT_VAL){
    // some code
}
```

However, when I changed the constant's type recently from `int` to `long`, I was getting a `noSuchMethodError` on the jsp calling it because the `Constants.DEFAULT_VAL` in the jsp still returns int and not long.

I have also changed all the methods like `hasModule` from taking an `int` as parameter to `long`.

Is there any special treatment for constants in java?

Thanks!

Comment: Click on your User name. You will see the profile. Click on the list of "Questions" and then you will see a white checked sign beneath the down arrow of all answers. Review all answers first and then mark the best answer that could solved problem. The check sign will change into a green sign. In case that no answer could solved your problem let it in white color.

Comment: @PinkAngel I hope you did the deployment right? Try clearing the temp/work folders and deploy and restart the server.

Comment: hello Prakash, 
I did what you said, I cleared my work folder and it works now! thanks a lot for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Because you posted just a line I can just guess.

JSP files -as the apprivtation stays for- uses Java for execution. Java allows you to overwrite methods.

Assume your Method in the particular class has the method 'hasModule(int numer)'. There is no problem if you pass an **int** value to that method. If you pass a long value to the method, the compiler or the JVM looks for a method with name 'hasModule()' with parameter signature of an **long** value. Does Java not found that method, your error message is one result of it.

Comment: Hi reporter, 
When I changed the Constants.DEFAULT_VAL from int to long, I also changed the method hasModule() from hasModule(int num) to hasModule(long num). And my JSP sees it accordingly, i.e. it now sees hasModule(long). My problem is the one returned by my Constant. It should now be returning a long (Constants.DEFAULT_VAL) but in the jsp, calling Constants.DEFAULT_VAL still returns and int.

Comment: I think you missunderstod me :-) Overwriting in Java has a different meaning. Try following: hasModule(int param) { //do something with int values } and hasModule(long param) { //do something with long values}. You can put they into the same class.